# effective catfish bait that stays on the hook without aidel

Tags: substitute-tool, sports

usually when im fishing for catfish i use regular old chicken livers but i find that depending on the age etc. that they sometimes regularly fall off the hook.  i know there are products and stuff but i was wondering if there was a good way to keep livers or any other bait you may suggest on the hook? the old heads who always fish by the river say to use beef heart but i have never tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take heavy-duty sewing thread and wrap around the bait several times. Wrap going down, wrap coming back, then tie off. Slide the hook into that and it will stay a long time.

Better yet, get a bunch of nylon mesh tubing used for crafts. Cut off pieces an inch in length, stuff the bait into that, then place on the hook.

http://www.cosplaysupplies.com/store.php?p=MJ-25402501-01

[image]

Comment: This is 98 feet for $11. Try different thicknesses for less bait and make it last a long time.